# find the container width

Tags: html, css

I have a discussion with a friend here, an example can be seen. Does the container have a width on `500px` or `580px`? By the content we mean from the sides of the banner picture, and a straight line all the way throughout the text.

We looked in the inspect window, but we cannot find where the width should be.

The site is made in tables, because the setup is for email newsletters.

An example where the width is set is in the html:

```
<!-- Top Picture Start -->
<table class="row background-color__blue">
    <tr>
        <td class="center img-position" align="center">
            <center>
                <table class="container">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                            <table class="twelve columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a class="remove-banner-space" href="http://google.dk"><img width="580" height="300" src="http://d21vu35cjx7sd4.cloudfront.net/dims3/MMAH/crop/586x293%2B0%2B95/resize/580x290%5E/quality/90/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets.prod.vetstreet.com%2F4a%2Ff0%2Fc29d3f434ae6abd19f5433140124%2Fborder-collie-AP-XO4EXW-590sm52314.jpg" alt="Test" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Top Picture End -->
```

In the CSS it should also be set to `580px`:

```
table.container {
            background: #fefefe;
            width: 580px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            Margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: inherit;
        }
```

Comment: It's 580px... if you highlight the element in dev tools, then look in the browser window, it should draw a box around the element and show the height/width.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, When I fx highlight the picture, I can see the width. But isnt there a way to see the width of the container?

Comment: Ah found out. Inherit from table.container. Thank you

Comment: This depends on the box-siding property. Read about it here : https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser tools/inspector (at least in Firefox) there is (among others) a tab called "calculated"  (not sure about the exact English term since in my case it's in another language). This shows you the calculated (i.e. actual) width, with everything that's added up to it: margin, border, padding, inner width - a good representation of the CSS box model.